# Eigenvalue of multiplicity k of a real symmetric matrix has exactly k linearly independent eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

If A is an nxn real symmetric matrix then A is diagonalisable. In other words, If A is a symmetric nxn matrix, then there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ such
that $P_{-1}AP=P_{T}AP=D$, a diagonal matrix. The eigenvalues of A lie on the
main diagonal of D.


Proof of this statement must be considered in two cases.


It is clear that all eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are real and if they are all distinct, then eigenvectors $x_i$, i=1,2,..,n  corresponding to $\lambda_i$ i=1,2,..,n are orthogonal. We can obtain an orthonormal set of eigenvectors eigenvectors $u_i$, i=1,2,..,n using these eigenvectors $x_i$, i=1,2,..,n Then we can construct matrix $P$ as $P=[u_1 u_2 ... u_n]$ such that $D=P_{-1}AP$.


I have some troubles in the second case that is not all eigenvalues are simple.

How can I prove that eigenvalue of  multiplicity k of a real symmetric matrix A has exactly k linearly independent eigenvectors, i.e., dimension of solution space of $(A-\lambda I)$ is k?

Comment: I typed $P_{-1}$ and $P_T$ wrong. The correct spelling is as follows  $P^{-1}$ and $P^T$.

Comment: Do some search... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871454/why-is-algebraic-multiplicity-always-equal-to-the-geometric-multiplicity-of-dist http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255622/symmetric-matrix-is-always-diagonalizable  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482599/why-symmetric-matrices-are-diagonalizable

Comment: @user1551 I noticed my mistake an I added a comment right after. Thanks again.

Comment: @leonbloy I have done my research. None of the questions you share gives an explicit proof for repeated eigenvalue case. In the proof of Theorem 7.9 in Kolman, Hill, Elementary Linear Algebra stated that "It can be shown  that if a symmetric matrix $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of multiplicity k, then the solution space of the homogeneous
system$ (A-\lambda I)x = 0 $ has dimension k. For a proof, see J. M. Ortega, Matrix Theory: A Secolld Course, New York: Plenum Press, 1987. This is about hermitian matrices but I could not find a proof in that book unfortunately.

Comment: I use the answer of this question to prove that ever real symmetric matrix is diagonalisable.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I added an answer.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482599/why-are-real-symmetric-matrices-diagonalizable

Comment: @HansLundmark I think you are voting to close as a duplicate incorrectly. You need to click the "duplicate" reason, rather than "other/add a comment". This is important because of review queues, where potential duplicates are treated in a specific way.

Comment: @user1729: OK, fair enough, I wasn't aware of that. It's just that I find the boilerplate “Does this answer your question?” comment (that's auto-generated when voting for duplicates in the usual way) very inappropriate in many cases. (OP starts debating, then the comment is auto-removed when the question is closed, and everything is left in a confusing-looking state. To name but one reason.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Sure - I guess clicking "duplicate", then deleting the auto-generated comment and adding your own would work then? Nicer comment, and easier for those coming later.

Comment: @user1729: Thanks for the suggestion, that makes sense. A bit of a hassle, though...

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes, but otherwise it is less likely that people will close the post as a duplicate (in the review queue I actually voted to leave open a question you had commented on, as your comment was hidden and the question looked fine). If you feel strongly about the wording, then you could bring it up on the meta site?

Comment: It's already been discussed on Meta: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31622/flagged-duplicate-does-this-answer-your-question-text-is-misleading, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391289/does-this-answer-your-question-duplicate-comment-text-is-silly-and-confusing, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390887/new-post-notices-closed-on-hold-etc-rolling-out-on-stack-overflow/390894#390894

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you have three ways:

1. Prove first that a symmetric matrix is diagonalizable. Then see that your desired property is true for diagonal matrices and that a similarity transform preserves both algebraic and geometric multiplicities (eg: see [prop 7.5 here](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~ars/MA106/week7.pdf)). I think this is the most usual way.
2. Continuity argument: in the space of symmetric matrices, we can go continuosly from different eigenvalues to repeated eigenvalues; because the starting point had orthogonal eigenvectors, these cannot degenerate in LD eigenvectors. This argument is easy to visualize but hard to formalize.
3. Prove it directly. Here's an sketch (essentially from [here](http://www.quandt.com/papers/basicmatrixtheorems.pdf))

Let ${\bf A}$ be a  $n \times n$ symmetric matrix, let $\lambda_i$ be an eigenvalue with (algebraic) multiplicity $1<m \le n$. Then there exists some eigenvector ${\bf p}_{i1}$ with $|{\bf p}_{i1}|=1$.

Let ${\bf B}=({\bf p}_{i1} \, {\bf C})$ be an orthogonal matrix (orthonormal columns) with ${\bf p}_{i1}$ as first column (it can be constructed by Grand-Schmidt process). Then consider

$$ {\bf B}' {\bf A} {\bf B} = 
\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_i &0 \\
0 & {\bf C}' {\bf A} {\bf C}
\end{pmatrix}$$

By considering the characteristic polynomial, we see that (because the multiplicity of $\lambda_i>1$)$|{\bf C}' {\bf A} {\bf C} -\lambda_i I_{n-1}|=0$
Hence there exists some non null ${\bf q}$ with $({\bf C}' {\bf A} {\bf C} -\lambda_i I_{n-1})){\bf q}=0$. Next, see that ${\bf p}_{i2}={\bf C}{\bf q}$ is eigenvector of ${\bf A}$, and is orthogonal to ${\bf p}_{i1}$. We can repeat the procedure (if $m>2$), by rebuilding ${\bf B}$ with this eigenvector as second column, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is very helpful for me.